# How to modify the effect of a Dockerfile RUN command based on an environment variable, passed from docker-compose.yml

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

To summarize, my project consists of:

- /docker-compose.yml
- /backend/Dockerfile (Docker file for "backend" service, a Yii2 REST api)
- /backend/.env (unversioned)
- /frontend/Dockerfile (Docker file for "frontend" service, an Angular2 app)
- /frontend/.env (unversioned)

So 2 services that are declared in the main docker-compose.yml and they each have their own (non-versioned) .env file where I'm declaring "environment specific" parameters, specific to the given service. E.g. for the backend service I define the DB username/password; for the frontend service, I declare the REST API URL from which the frontend should retrieve its data through Ajax.

I am passing /backend/.env to the backend service and /frontend/.env to the frontend service through the main docker-compose.yml using the `env_file` parameter.

**Both services are hosted on different domains (example.com and api.example.com).**

Given that how Angular 2 handles its configuration, you can not declare OS level environment variables and let Angular use them at runtime inside the application (e.g. to read the "BACKEND_URL" from the env variable and make Ajax calls to it). Instead, it expects all environment params to be present during the build process in a file called /src/app/environment.prod.ts. I managed to create this config file through a RUN command in /frontend/Dockerfile, but I am struggling with filling it with the dynamic values, declared in the unversioned /frontend/.env. I don't want to hardcode stuff in /frontend/Dockerfile.

Once the /frontend/Dockerfile generates the static /src/app/environment.prod.ts with the correct values (e.g. `BACKEND_URL=http://api.example.com`), then the rest of the build process will be fine and the frontend application will pick up these values.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as you have already pointed out, is that environment/env_file declarations in docker compose are applied to RUN, but not build. To pass parameters from via docker-compose to docker build, you would have to specify ARGS in your Dockerfile, as documented [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg). Then, you can pass in the predefined args from your compose file as shown [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build).

However, I feel that approach introduces too much coupling and repeated declarations. I'm more inclined to your approach of segregating environment definitions into separate files.

In addition to what you already have, you only need to define an entrypoint shell script to the respective containers, which are capable of consuming environment variables, and generating angular environment bindings `environment.prod.ts` before the application starts.